How to combine two parent selectors in SASS mixins?
Given the following SCSS:
@mixin one() {
  html.one & {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin two() {
  html.two & {
    @content;
  }
}

div {
  background: green;

  @include one() {
    background: blue;

    @include two() {
      background: yellow;
    }
  }
}

This results in:
div {
  background: green;
}
html.one div {
  background: blue;
}
html.two html.one div {
  background: yellow;
}

How must the mixins be changed, so that the html element has both classes one and two?
My desired result is:
div {
  background: green;
}
html.one div {
  background: blue;
}
html.one.two div {
  background: yellow;
}

In other words I want to be able to use both mixins nested. It should play no rule which is the outer and inner one. The classes on the html tags should always be combined.

Alright, this was a little challenging but I found a solution:
@use "sass:selector";
@mixin two() {
  @at-root #{selector.replace(&,'html','html.two')} {
    @content;
  }
}

We use @at-root so that the selector we provide is not nested with its parent.
We then use the parent selector and replace the 'html' part to add the .two class selector.
Now this works but I'm worried that it wouldn't work correctly if the classes were applied on some other element whose name could repeat, as the replace function replaces all instances of the found string.
Edit: I tried to add a class to your div selector to test how the replace reacts. I used div.html-content my understanding was that it would be transformed to div.html.div-content but no. The selector.replace function actually looks for complete selector, it does not simply acts like a string replace.

https://sass-lang.com/playground/#eJy9jssKgzAQRff5iqEFH1AFt2bjr2gcrDRmSh61RfLv1VSpLXTb1XCZ+zhFUTmDcDC1MaVBicKSPnBWDf29V0AKkxQmBnC2g8xnCVGQAJUgZVFZPivPPNsidqQ1UtU200QWjtPWnGu8ylpgEp3ipTF+nXwOxan/1dz2t/BqanHpNDnVltBpRMXZMtMrIV2LO9hPayMdBufO+6b8dj9QShp5+PiNYEHIF9JsZZv+MvwEeed8rw==

This works great when two() is the inner mixin. But what if the order is different? I mean div { @include two() { @include one() { ... } } }?

Also unfortunately two doesnt work as a standalone mixin anymore: div { @include two() { ... } } results in div { ... }
